# How do I generate non-repeating random numbers in a while loop? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop

So far what I have is

```
import random
def go():
    rounds = 0
    while rounds < 5:
        number = random.randint(1, 5)
        if number == 1:
            print('a')
        elif number == 2:
            print('b')
        elif number == 3:
            print('c')
        elif number == 4:
            print('d')
        elif number == 5:
            print('e')
        rounds = rounds + 1
go()
```

and the output ends up beings something along the lines of

```
e
e
c
b
e
```

How do I make it so a number is only used once and the letters do not repeat?
(ex. something like)

```
a
e
b
c
d
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can try `random.sample("abcde", 5)` [random library python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/random.html)

Comment: your specific code example suggests that you want `L = list("abcde"); random.shuffle(L)` i.e., get a random permutation of `"abcde"` letters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [random.sample(population, k)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) method returns a sample of unique values from the specified population of length k.

```
r = random.sample("abcde", 5)
for element in r:
    print(element)
```

Comment: @zeurosis if it worked for you please select it as the accepted answer

Comment: sorry how do I do that? I haven't used this website a whole lot

Comment: @zeurosis click the check mark under the upvote/downvote icons on the left of the post

Comment: @zeurosis you might want to do that on your previous questions as well ;)

Comment: `random.sample("abcde", 5)` is a weird way to [emulate `random.shuffle()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596805/how-do-i-generate-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-a-while-loop-python-3#comment53047864_32596805)